# Scaling vertex coordinates of marching cubes algorithm output in skimage

Tags: coordinates, scaling, scikit-image, coordinate-transformation, marching-cubes

I am trying to use [`skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=marching_cubes_lewiner#skimage.measure.mesh_surface_area) to resolve some isosurface `f(x,y,z)=0`. In my case `f` is strongly nonlinear, and is best mapped when coordinates are given with logarithmic spacing. Because the marching cubes wants a regular grid, to build the voxels, I am working on a meshgrid of coordinates `X,Y,Z` which correspond to the `log10` of my original coordinates, so that my isosurface is equivalently given by `f(10**X,10**Y,10**Z)=0`. Everything would be fine, if it were not for the fact that, say I am working with `X,Y,Z` in `[-1.5,2]^3` (equivalent to `x,y,z` in `[0.03,100.]^3`), the vertex coordinates of the solution given by `skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner`, are not in this cube.

Following the answer to another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586158/clarification-on-marching-cubes-algorithm) on SO, I thought it could be due to the fact that, probably the algorithm works thinking of a unitary volume, so that I need to set the right `spacing` input argument in my call of `skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner`. In this fashion, say I am mapping my function `f` on a grid of `N` points per coordinate, so that I am increasing exponents by `numpy.diff([-1.5,2])/N` per coordinate, I accordingly call:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure as msr

def f(x,y,z):
    val = ... # some lengthy code to define my implicit function
    return val 

# Define ranges of my coordinates
xRange = [0.03,100.]
yRange = [0.03,100.]
zRange = [0.03,100.]

XRange = np.log10(xRange)
YRange = np.log10(yRange)
ZRange = np.log10(zRange)   

# Create regular grid
N = 50  # number of points per coordinate
X,Y,Z = np.mesh[XRange[0]:XRange[1]:N*1j,
                YRange[0]:YRange[1]:N*1j,
                ZRange[0]:ZRange[1]:N*1j]
F = f(10**X,10**Y,10**Z)
sol,_,_,_ = skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(F,0.0,spacing(np.diff(XRange)/N,np.diff(YRange)/N,np.diff(ZRange)/N))
```

yet, unexpectedly, the coordinates of the solution points generally seem in `[0,Vx]*[0,Vy]*[0,Vz]` with `Vx>XRange[-1]`, `Vy>YRange[-1]` and `Vz>ZRange[-1]`. I have no clue of why this happens and how I could properly rescale the coordinates of my isosurface solution, to the real units of my problem.

Comment: Anyone can help on this? Is it perhaps that I simply need to shift the vertex coordinates by `XRange[0]`, `YRange[0]` and `ZRange[0]`. Doing this trick results seems consistent, but I cannot cross-check unless I outsource a different implementation of MCs in python (other than the `skimage.measure` one).

Comment: In case someone gets stucked on this same issue, it seems that my above comment is the answer to my question. But before I post it separately, unless someone confirms it meanwhile, I want first to compare the solutions for my isosurface solution `skimage.measure` 's MCs with those independently estimated by global solvers.

Comment: Maybe you could open an issue in the scikit-image GitHub repo, linking this question. https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues Maybe it is just a documentation issue or maybe it is an implementation issue. In any case, I think you should let them know :)